# Error Target Unreachable, identifier 'registrationBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7

I have an Enterprise Application in NetBeans comprising of 2 modules: test-ejb (EJB project) and test-war(Web application). In the web application I have a JSF page that makes a call to a method of a managed bean that exists in the test-ejb.

Inside register.xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton id="register" value="Register" action="#{registrationBean.doRegister}" />
```

The RegistrationBean.java is inside com.testpackage and has a method:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationBean {

    public String doRegister() {
        return "confirmation";
    }
}
```

Those two modules are automatically deployed by NetBeans in a JBoss 7.1 AS. When I run the web application and click the register button I get on my browser:

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'registrationBean' resolved to null
```

My question is, how can I call a method of the RegistrationBean.java that resides in a different module than the web application.

As a solution I tried to add the .jar file of the EJB Module in the libraries of the web application, but it didn't help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not an answer, but *why*? `@ManagedBean`s are not EJBs, so they should be included in your war module, if you decide to split out EJBs (which is fine in itself, but do ship it as a jar inside the war).

Comment: You are right. I should place the RegistrationBean in the war module. But still, that RegistrationBean needs to "talk" to other EJBs in the ejb module.

Comment: And it should. You ought to be able to simply inject (use `@EJB` or `@Inject`) your EJB beans into the `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: I try with both @ EJB and @ Inject and I get an error while deploying the war saying: "No EJB found with interface of type 'com.testpackage.RegistrationManagerBean'". The RegistrationManagerBean is the EJB that I want to make the call to. Any ideas?